# Arduino UNO and ESP8266 how to send http respond

Tags: http, arduino, esp8266

i connect esp8266 to Arduino-Uno ([WiFi Controlled LED using ESP8266 and Arduino](http://www.electronicshub.org/wifi-controlled-led-using-esp8266-and-arduino/)) it's working well.
but, when in browser i call (http://192.168.1.***/?led=ON) i want esp8266 respond and display message like that is (Ok/No) on that page, can we do that with AT Commands? or any other way ...

```
void loop() {
 if (esp8266.available()) {
  if (esp8266.find("+IPD,")) {

String msg;
esp8266.find("?");
msg = esp8266.readStringUntil(' ');
String command1 = msg.substring(0, 3);
String command2 = msg.substring(4);

if (DEBUG) {
  Serial.println(command1); // Must print "led"
  Serial.println(command2); // Must print "ON" or "OFF"
}

delay(100);

if (command2 == "ON") {
  digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
  // here i want send led is on now
} else {
  digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
  // here i want send led is off now
}

  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ESP8266WebServer library for this project. You can create an HTML page with two separate input buttons with arguments On and Off, You can then change the status of your URL from on to off and vice-versa. On the ESP side, You can get the status of arguments like this

```
if(server.hasArg("ON")==true){
    digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
}else if(server.hasArg("OFF")==true){
    digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH);
}
```

I have done a similar kind of project
https://ncd.io/thingspeak-weather-app-using-esp8266/
and  https://github.com/vbshightime/ESPMeshServer

Answer (score 0):

this methode:

```
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>

const int LED_PIN = 16;

IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 32);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 0, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);

WebServer server(9999);    

void handleLED();

void setup(void){

  WiFi.config(ip, gateway, subnet);   
  WiFi.begin("ssid","pw");
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }   

  server.on("/ON", HTTP_GET, handleLED_ON);  
  server.on("/OFF", HTTP_GET, handleLED_OFF);     
  server.begin();

  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("Start");
}

void loop(void){

  server.handleClient(); 

}

void handleLED_ON() {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH);
    server.send(200,"text/plan","OK");
}

void handleLED_OFF() {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    server.send(200,"text/plan","OK");
}
```